# Modify the siderbar footer

Tags: widgets

I have to update a website made with wordpress, and I can't find how to change the "sidebar footer".

here's the link to the website: [somatbel.be](http://www.somatbel.be)

the part I want to change is right under the last menu item(contact), it starts by "contactez nous". When I inspect that part with google chroem its says "box widget". I'm new to wordpress, I look into the widget, menu sections but there is nothing there.

Comment: You'll need to post actual code, or else we have no way of offering any help.

Comment: Hi, in the editor where can I find the appropriate code for this element? I thought everything was edited with wp panel, for example I can't even modify the start/main page content. But thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: I found where to edit to change the information, in the appearance menu> edit>header.php file. Is it normal to find the code for a sidebar footer( under the name Contact list widget) in the header file?